# css with media queries does not work properly when screen size is small

Tags: html, css

I have created a responsive website using Swiper. I have used @media queries in my css to fit different screen size and orientation.

Initially, I have 1 main css, 1 landscape css and 1 vertical css. I imported two orientation css into main css. Only main css is  in html file. The website works fine with all screen sizes. The css snippet regarding the media is as below:

```
  @media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (min-width:700px) {

  @media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (min-aspect-ratio:16/10) {

  @media screen and (orientation:portrait)
```

Then I read about not using import for css so I `cat` all .css into one file. I also deleted the two `@import` lines. Then the website does not work properly. Specifically, all elements on small screens return to normal size. I checked the css structure: these elements lose their style enclosed in `@media {}` thus inherent from their parent css.

The fiddle with all the code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/6n8q479y/2/). It's not working because it supposes to grab local image files.

The working website with separate css files is [this](http://cutelittleturtle.github.io). It's on Github so you can see the source files easily.

I am really new to css so this might be due a stupid mistake..

Comment: This is what the fiddle outputs, }//]]>

This is not css related

Comment: I did not see that output from my end. I just see a blank screen with nav arrow and pagination for the Swiper. I am sure it is css related because all I have to do to get it work is to switch from the all-in-one css file to separate files.

Comment: It's me being stupid. I missed `}` for one of my `@media` component. So when combined together the latter css become buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these media screen for tablet and mobile if you are not importing hopefully it will help Thank's 
beside your fiddle shows this on top  }//]]> i dont know why might be js issue or some text in body

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){}
```

Comment: why two `max-width:` at 768px and 767px ?

Comment: You should add `min-width` as well, because, for example, on 1440px screen width all 3 rulesets will be applied.

Comment: It's me being stupid. I missed one `}` to close one of my `@media` tags. It now works fine combined. Thank you for your help.